# Can't add css style to html file

Tags: html, css, flask

I have got a question about adding css style to html file. I am trying to create my own online page using library flask. I have tried to add css style from my computer into html document using following syntax:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='style.css') }}">
```

but only result was, it displayed me an error, that the page /static/style.css doesn't exist. I have also tried this piece of code:

```html
<style>
    @import url("css/style.css");
</style>
```

but this time it haven't done anything. Please, can someone help me, how to solve this? Here I am also posting the
[picture of my poject folder.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xMtIH.png)

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Your first attempt looks right. can you check at the flask console what request you get for fetching the style.css?

Comment: I got this: IP_ADRESS - - [19/Feb/2022 21:05:23] "GET /home HTTP/1.1" 200 -
IP_ADRESS - - [19/Feb/2022 21:05:23] "GET /style.css HTTP/1.1" 404 -

Comment: This is not reproducible in my env, the GET goes to `/static/style.css` and not `/style.css` that you see in yours, it works correct and as described here: https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/quickstart/#static-files. are you modifying flask variables "static_url_path" or "static_folder" by any chance?

Comment: The HTML in the picture also shows `rel='nooperner'`. That's likely cancelling out the `rel='stlyesheet'`.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, See First Your Html File Is In templates and you're importing css file in static so fist we need to move out of templates so,

Replace:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='style.css') }}">
```

To:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../static/style.css">
```

There you go.

Comment: Thank you, this syntax can access the file, but it doesn't aply the style to the html text as I wish